# Any suggestion to split a long list of data and put it in new columns?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.6

I have a list with 11000 instances in a CSV file and I would like to split them and put them in new columns. I could not figure out a way to do it.

By the way, there are spaces between the data to separate them.

This is a little sample of the data.

```
47    769639.50
48    750000.00
49    403149.50
50   1321000.00
51    840000.00

52   2018060.00
53    740000.00
54    575900.00
55    250000.00
56    850000.00

57    759796.00
58    999029.00
59    610000.00
60    700000.00
61    540906.00
```

The desired output is

```
47    769639.50  52   2018060.00  57    759796.00
48    750000.00  53    740000.00  58    999029.00
49    403149.50  54    575900.00  59    610000.00
50   1321000.00  55    250000.00  60    700000.00
51    840000.00  56    850000.00  61    540906.00
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @slider I tried to use empty lists to return sliced data to them + many different means. Anyway, the outputs of my programs did not give me anything close to the desired output, so I did not post them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy could be create groups of lines and `zip` those groups before writing to your output file:

```
result = []

with open('input.csv') as f:
  lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
  num_groups = lines.count('') + 1
  group_len = lines.index('')
  # create groups of lines lists
  result = [lines[start * (group_len + 1) : start * (group_len + 1) + group_len] for start in range(num_groups)]

with open('output.csv', 'w') as of:
  for line in zip(*result):
    of.write('\t'.join(line) + '\n')
```

This gives us the following output file:

```
47    769639.50 52   2018060.00 57    759796.00
48    750000.00 53    740000.00 58    999029.00
49    403149.50 54    575900.00 59    610000.00
50   1321000.00 55    250000.00 60    700000.00
51    840000.00 56    850000.00 61    540906.00
```

Comment: amazing! This solution works for me!